# Datatables jQuery get row data mobile/pc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have mobile view responsible datatable and I need to get row data.

When table is in mobile view with collapse/expand buttons I can get row data using following code:

```
$("#myTable").on('click','.btn-action',function(){      
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  var data = table.row(this).data();
  alert(data); // returning array of row data

        });
```

But when my table is in standard mode, for PC view code above returning: undefined.

How can I make 1 function which always returns row data, regardless of the table view, mobile or not.

Thank you very much in advance

All page code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>JPT parking</title>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JQUERY -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!--Datatables CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.7/css/rowReorder.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">
    
  </style>
  
  <style>
    .modalInput{
        min-width: 200px ;
        text-transform:uppercase;

    }


    .tblRow {
        text-transform:uppercase
    }

    .hdn{
        display: none;
    }

    *{padding:0;margin:0;}

    .svg {
        width:40px;
        height:40px;

    }


    .float{
        position:fixed;
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
        bottom:40px;
        right:40px;
        background-color:#007BFF;
        color:#FFF;
        border-radius:50px;
        text-align:center;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;

    }

    .my-float{

    }

</style>

<!--Datatables JQUERY-->

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.7/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
  
  
    
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    


$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {

    bLengthChange: false,
    searching: false,

    responsive: true,
    fixedHeader: {
        headerOffset: $('#mainNav').outerHeight()
    }
    
    
   
   
  } );


  $("#myTable").on('click','.btn-action',function(){
           
  
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  var data = table.row(this).data();
  
  console.log(data);





        });

  ///
 





} );





    </script>
    









</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
     <!-- <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">JPT Parking</a> -->
      <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/arrived">On Parking
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/depart">Departed</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/all">All</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


 <!-- TABLE -->

    
    <div class="container-sm container-table" >

      <table id="myTable" class="table  table-striped table-bordered table-hover " style="width:100%; padding-top: 100px;">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              
                <th data-priority="0" style="padding-right:3%;">Trailer</th>
                <th data-priority="4" style="padding-right:3%;">Truck</th>
                <th data-priority="5" style="padding-right:3%;">Name</th>
                <th data-priority="6" style="padding-right:3%;">Lastname</th>
                <th data-priority="3" style="padding-right:3%;">Date</th>
                <th data-priority="1" style="padding-right:3%;">Dep</th>
                <th data-priority="2" style="padding-right:3%;">Status</th>
                <th data-priority="7" style="padding-right:3%;" >Oper</th>
                <th data-priority="8" style="padding-right:3%;">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>aaaaa</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>2011/04/25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>iglac</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-action">Action</button></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>bbbbb</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>iglac</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-action">Action</button></td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
      
      
      <tfoot>

      </tfoot>
       

    
    </table>

  </div>


  <div  class="float btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" onclick="$('#trlModalAdd').modal('show')">

      <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-circle svg my-float" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
      </svg>

</div>

    </div>
 


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Boris <br>boshl@dfds.com</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->



  </footer>

</div>


            <div  class="float btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl" onclick="$('#trlModalAdd').modal('show')">

                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-circle svg my-float" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                </svg>

    </div>

<!-- Modal Add Trailer -->
<div class="modal fade" id="trlModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trlModalLabelAdd" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="modalAdd">
      <div class="modal-content" >
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="trlModalLabelAdd">New trailer arrival</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

              <form class="form" id="addform" method="post" action="/trl/add" >

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="trailer" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" >Trailer</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" id="trailer" class="form-control modalInput" name="inTrl" type="text" placeholder="Trailer"  required  >
                      </div>
                  </div>




                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="truck" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Truck</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" style="text-transform:uppercase" id="truck" class="form-control modalInput" name="inTruck"  type="text" placeholder="Truck" required >
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" style="text-transform:uppercase" id="name" class="form-control modalInput" name="inName"  type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Lastname</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" style="text-transform:uppercase" id="lastname" class="form-control modalInput"  name="inLname" type="text" placeholder="Lastname" required >
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="indatepicker" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">


                          <div id="indatepicker" class="input-group date modalInput" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                              <input class="form-control date readonly modalInput"  name="inDate" type="text" placeholder="Date" required readonly />
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                          </div>



                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="department" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Department</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <select id="department" class="form-control modalInput" name="dep" required >
                              <option value="" selected disabled>Select department</option>
                              <option>SE-Baltic</option>
                              <option>UK-Baltic</option>
                              <option>Concrete</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Status</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <select id="status" class="form-control modalInput" name="status"  required >
                              <option value="" disabled selected>Select status</option>
                              <option>Empty</option>
                              <option>Loaded</option>
                              <option>Stack</option>
                              <option style="color:darkred;">Need repair</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >Save changes</button>


                  <br>
                  <br>


                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

                          <div class="form-check">
                              <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="email"  value="yes" checked hidden>
                              <input pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" value="no">
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="email">
                                  Don't send e-mail
                              </label>

                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>

          </div>



      </div>
  </div>
</div>

  
 


  

</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited to account for child row:**

I think you need to navigate to the tr before passing it to the DataTable. When expanded, the child tr should have a class of "child".

```js
$("#myTable").on('click','.btn-action',function(){      
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    var tr = $(this.closest('tr'));
    if(tr.hasClass('child')){
        tr = tr.prev();
    }
    var data = table.row(tr).data();
    alert(data); // returning array of row data

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to pass that button's corresponding row TR element into table.row(...)

Something like

```
table.row($(this).closest("tr")[0]).data();
```

Comment: this way will work to the full wide table, but when table will be minimizet and will have expand buttons, this code will return 'undefined '